# How do I center OpenLayers map over Chile

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to center an OpenLayers map over Chile and having a hard time to get it working.

Here is my code:
This doesn't center on OpenLayers map over Chile.

```
var osmLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
          source: new ol.source.OSM()
        });
        // Create latitude and longitude and convert them to default projection
        var birmingham = ol.proj.transform([150.644, -34.397], 'EPSG:5186', 'EPSG:3857');
        // Create a View, set it center and zoom level
        var view = new ol.View({
          center: birmingham,
          zoom: 6
        });
        // Instanciate a Map, set the object target to the map DOM id
        var map = new ol.Map({
          target: 'map_new'
        });
        // Add the created layer to the Map
        map.addLayer(osmLayer);
        // Set the view for the map
        map.setView(view);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should insert the coordinates of the map center you want (for example, of Santiago de Chile):

```
 var view = new ol.View({
     center: [-33.27, -70.38],
     zoom: 6
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Every GIS map has a coordinate system. GIS web applications are very similar to desktop GIS maps, so they have a coordinate system too. in OpenLayers known as projection.

In OpenLayers, every web app made up of a `Map()` class that needs a `view()` to show the map. By default, every `view()` use `Web Mercator projection` or `EPSG:3857` as its projection. The idea of transforming `EPSG:5186` to `EPSG:3857` is right but according to [espg.io](http://epsg.io/5186), `EPSG:5186` is `Korea 2000 / Central Belt 2010`!
So I think you are using the wrong transformation. if you want WGS 84 (lat-long system) simply use one of the codes below:

```
view: new ol.View({
    center: [-70.66, -33.44],
    projection: 'EPSG:4326',
    zoom: 0
})
```

Or:

```
view: new ol.View({
    center: ol.proj.fromLonLat([-70.66, -33.44]),
    zoom: 0
})
```

Or:

```
var birmingham = ol.proj.transform([-70.66, -33.44], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857');
```